# POST http://localhost:5000/api/creatuser 400 (Bad Request) when trying to send data from client to server

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, backend, mern

Hey guys so i've got some problem with sending data from client-side to server-side. Basically when I try to send the new user details to server, I get the following error.

an Alert with the message "Enter valid credentials"
and "POST http://localhost:5000/api/creatuser 400 (Bad Request)"
0: {msg: 'Invalid value', param: 'email', location: 'body'}
1:location: "body"msg: "Password not strong enough"param: "password"[[Prototype]]: Object

client side code

```
function Signup() {
  const [credentials, setcredentials] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    location: ""
  });
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/creatuser", {
    //   mode: "no-cors",
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: credentials.name,
        email: credentials.email,
        password: credentials.password,
        location: credentials.location
      }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);

    if (!json.success) {
      alert("Enter valid credentials");
    }
  };
  const onChange = (event) => {
    setcredentials({ ...credentials, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

Server side code

```
router.post("/creatuser", 
[ body('email').isEmail(),
body('name').isLength(),
body('password', 'Password not strong enough').isLength({ min: 5 })],
async(req, res)=>{
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    try {
        await User.create({
            name : req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
            location: req.body.location
        })

        res.json({success:true});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.json({success:false});
    }
})
```

Not sure what i did wrong, i haven't worked much with backend so don't have much knowledge either, any help very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I see in the docs of `express-validator` that no array is used as the second argument but all validators are passed in seperately,

```
app.post(
  '/user',
  // username must be an email
  body('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  body('password').isLength({ min: 5 }),
  (req, res) => {
    // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
```